# Exporting grid to excel + OOXML

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Earlier we used BIFF to export the grid to excel but there is a limitation of rows so that we thought of moving to OOXML format. Is there any sample source available to get started. Please help me with this as i am new to Delphi.

Comment: What grid are you using? the TStringGrid, or TDBGrid?

Comment: @Zeina That doesn't matter. The question is about OOXML.

Comment: I think there are a few good components out there. Are you prepared to pay.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Not really, I should start developing of my own.

Comment: depending upon actually needed features, you may have a look upon Z XML-SS library. It only supports very simplistic and basic features subset (but at least more than FPC's fpSpreadSheet) and Excel bugs are poppign up here and there, but that may be enopugh strating point for you. My temporary fork is at https://github.com/the-Arioch/avemey.com/wiki however original author also made few large changes recently. We both are a bit busy for a while to catch-up each other though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would just use the built in DevExpress export to Excel facility. It will save you *days* of work:

cxGridExportLink.pas : ExportGridToExcel [doesn't use OOXML] or ExportGridToXLSX [does use OOXML via custom DX xml document class amongst other things]

However, if you must use a DIY OpenXML approach then the best places to start are:

- http://ericwhite.com/blog/category/open-xml/spreadsheetml/
- http://openxmlviewer.codeplex.com/
- http://powertools.codeplex.com/

These are all C# references but it's not too difficult to translate, mainly because it's the XML you're after anyway. I did some work reading and writing to Word and Excel using the OpenXML stuff and the only way to learn it was by opening up an existing document using the OpenXML viewer and trawling through the sheets / rows / cells trying to work out how it all fits together. It's not easy and the docs are hard work and limited. It's sort of satisfying when you start to work it out but it sure is time consuming.

EDIT

Just realised that the DX stuff I have is TcxGrid  - ie not the earlier TdxDBGrid. Not sure if that will make a difference in this scenario.

Comment: Perhaps it does - I may be wrong on that front :-)   I only just noticed that function was available as I always use the plain old ExportGridToExcel. If you've ever tried to trace through DevExpress grid code you'll know it's not an easy thing to unravel and I don't have all the source to hand at the moment.

Comment: Well, XLSX is an OOXML format. So that's pretty easy to unravel. I'm sure the code is a different story.

Comment: True. XML is easy to read - but SpreadsheetML adds plenty of complexity, although creating a simple sheet is not too strenuous.  Nevertheless, the main point remains - Use what they've already written and move on to coding something else :)

Comment: OK. Just looked through the source briefly. They have their own XML document class and add the OOXML stuff bit by bit. So, yes, I was wrong about not using it and will edit the post. But... on first inspection there is nearly 9,000 lines of code to run the export process for an XLSX. Definitely seems worth not re-inventing the wheel!

Comment: Yes, I agree about not reinventing wheel. I've seen quite a lot of dire devExpress code that does exactly that mind you. So, if you are going to re-use a pre-existing wheel, it's always best to choose one that is round!  ;-)

Comment: @David XLSX is an OOXML format de jure, but not de facto. Google around, there are a lot of issues that Excel fails reading valid XLSX documents. BTW Excel XP/2003 fails different way from Excel 2007/2010. My personal gotcha, that i banged my head over for a day, is that "0.0E0" is not a number for Excel in XLSX format. It is a number in XML-SS format, and in XLSX format "0" or "0.0" or "1.0E0" are numbers as well. But... but "0.0E0" in XLSX format just is string, forever. And Excel is full of this "you should have guessed better" things, when dealing with XLSX. OOXML validator <> Excel :-E

Comment: @shunty SpreadsheetML for me makes the most complexity that you cannot just ShellExecute it. Depending on software installed on client PC (out of your control), that may end openiong Excel or web-browser or XML editor or whatever. Not a showstopper, but surely a nuisance.

Comment: @shunty: I was looking into the function ExportGridToXLSX in cxGridExportLink file and i am not getting any clue about it. Can you shed more light on which piece of code i need to understand

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Is there any code i can reuse from the existing developer express?

Comment: @Jeeva Almost certainly, but you need to pay for it. Arioch gave you some links to stuff that's free.

Comment: @Jeeva : With all due respect, if you are having a hard time getting any clue about the DX source at the start then you're going to find it a whole lot harder as you go on. Nevertheless, ExportGridToXLSX creates a TcxGridCustomExportClass object such as TcxGridTableViewExport. This, in turn, uses a "Provider" member which is an IcxExportProvider implementation. In this case it is a TdxXLSXExportProvider in unit dxXLSXExport.pas. Start at TcxGridCustomExport.DoExport and follow the tortuous path from there...